# I lost the key to my 97 ES300 Lexus

Tags: lexus, replacements, smartkey, es-300

I have a Lexus ES 300 97 and I lost the key is there a Toyota compatible with the electronic control module key key fob so I can go to the junkyard and hopefully get a new one instead of paying $500 to get a chip key made

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

Comment: Whether you have a spare remote key or not, you should be able to buy replacements but either Toyota or a locksmith program it/them. A locksmith should cost less than dealers. Some older models allows diy programming; searching online may help.